# How can I unlink a file and copy a new file in its place?

Tags: php, copy-paste

**What I Have:**

I have a site that contains directories called 003 through 743.
Each directory contains a file called bb.php.
All the bb.php files are Chmod 644.

**What I Need to Do:**

I need copy a new bb.php file into each directory.

**What I've Accomplished So Far:**

I created a script that unlinks the old file and copies a new file into the directories.
It works up to directory 304. 305 onward won't unlink the file or copy the new file into the directory.

Here's my code:

```
$dir_path=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

$handle = opendir($dir_path);
while($name = readdir($handle)) {
    if (is_numeric($name) && $name > 304) {
        $new_file=$dir_path.'/bb.php';
        $file=$dir_path.'/'.$name.'/bb.php';
        if (!unlink($file)) {
            print "DIDN'T UNLINK<br>";
        }
        print "<p>$new_file<br>$file</p>";
        if(!copy($new_file, $file)) { 
        print "DIDNT COPY $file<br>";
        }
    }
}
closedir($handle);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you confirm that the directory permissions and owner is who you are expecting it to be? As well as the ownership of the file. Not just the permissions?

Comment: Just realized the the directories 305 onward are chmod 755. I changed one to 777 and the script worked. I've added a line to change the directories to 777 (chmod(0777)) but it's not working. I checked ownership using print_r(posix_getpwuid($stat['uid'])). They all have the same [name].

Comment: In Dreamweaver I selected all the 764 directories and was able to change them all at once to 777. But thanks for the replay.